# PHP add function to every file (even when called directly)

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible in php to add some custom function `my_custom_function()` to be accessable in **every file in given directory**?

What I mean is that if I **call some file directly** (for example during ajax call) like

```
my-directory-to-have-function/some-dir/dir/my-file.php
```

and `my-file.php` would be

```
echo my_custom_function();
```

and lets say we have

```
function my_custom_function() {
    return 5;
}
```

declared in `my-directory-to-have-function/global-functions-in-this-dir.php`

Also **I cannot modify server config**, I can add **.htacces** file however.

I know I can just **inlcude** file with function definitions but I'm wondering if it's possible without doing it. - it would be great to dont care about including common tools to every file loaded directly.

Comment: are you looking for include? http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: why don't you include function file in that file where the function is called? by `include("your_function_file_path.php");`

Comment: becouse in cases like wordpress its quite unclean to do include(../../../../../wp-load.php); Even more when you change your folders structure at some point.

Comment: Try looking for some auto-loading class (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to additionally include needed files alongside of your other classes

Comment: But then I need to include this auto-loading class. I know what you mean here and I'm ok with that, I just was thinking if I'm able to avoid those includes in every file that is loaded directly. I know I can use amazing tools to make it after I include them. To make my point clear - my question is about avoidin need of including anything and having it somehow included for example by .htdocs file.

Comment: Why you guys downvote it? I think it would be great to dont care about including some common tools to every file called directly. You DRY then as by including you need to do same thing in every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this to your `.htaccess` file instead.

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/dir/path/utilities.php"
```

This would automatically include your PHP file to every page request.